# Simultanious Animation of Elements in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, user-interface, rotation

I have a question according WPF animation in 3D.

In my user control, there are a dynamic number of wpf elements that are created in code behind. They are positioned circularly around the y-axis.

I create each element with an initial angle:

```
var trans = new AxisAngleRotation3D();
trans.Axis = new Vector3D(0, 1, 0);
trans.Angle = initialAngleFromZero;
RotateTransform3D elementTransform = new RotateTransform3D(trans);
wpfElement.Transform = elementTransform;
```

Each element is then displayed as desired.

Now, I want to rotate all of the dynamically created objects around the y-axis by the same angle at the same time in code behind. How do I that? I have tried the following:

```
foreach(var wpfElement in wpfElements)
{
   var sb = new Storyboard();
   var ani = new DoubleAnimation();
   ani.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
   ani.From = fromAngle;
   ani.To = toAngle;
   sb.Children.Add(ani);
   Storyboard.SetTarget(ani, wpfElement.Transform);
   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(ani, new PropertyPath(AxisAngleRotation3D.AngleProperty));
   sb.Begin();
}
```

But this does not work, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a group animation like that, or to animate multiple objects at once, you might find that you have more success by developing a custom `Panel`... you can build the animation right into it and once developed, you just set it as the `ItemsPanel` for a UI collection control and add items to see it animate. I have several and use them like this:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Controls:AnimatedRotationPanel EntryAnimationType="Slide" 
EntryAnimationDirection="Up" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
ExitAnimationType="Slide" ExitAnimationDirection="Down" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

As you can see, I added extra properties to the `Panel` to provide more options when using it, but you can make yours as simple or complicated as you want. To help you out with developing these `Panel`s, please take a look at the following links and please don't get put off by what at first, seems like some challenging code:

> [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN
>   [How to create a Custom Layout Panel in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html) on WPF Tutorial.NET
>   [Creating Custom Panels In WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37348/Creating-Custom-Panels-In-WPF) from CodeProject
>   [Animated WPF Panels](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153554/Animated-WPF-Panels) from CodeProject